# How can I fix Qt apps texts & menus in ubuntu 18.04 bionic beaver?

Tags: fonts, 18.04, qt

QT is not cute in ubuntu 18.04 ! See below screenshots. I have the same issue with scribus and vlc.

I tried deleting all config files that I know about, no change.
I tried both qt4-config and qt5ct, without success (changes made in fonts tab of these utilities have absolutely no effect).

What else can I try ?

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: What screen resolution are you using? If you're using HiDPI, I don't think Qt4 has support to adjust the application scale.

Comment: No, classic 1920x1080 on 23".

Comment: Did you find a solution? What is `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME` set to? I think it needs to be set to `qt5ct` for it to work.

Comment: It is empty, and setting it to qt5ct doesn't change anything.